# getting network streams using tcplistener for mulitple connections

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcplistener, networkstream

I'm trying to have different Network Stream for each client that i'm listening to (using TCPListener)
here's an example code:

```
while(listener.Pending())
{
Socket sock = listener.AcceptSocket();
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sock);
list.Add(stream);
}
```

my question is, will the list consist of different network streams, one for each client that tries to make connection?
ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll get one NetworkStream per socket, and `Accept`ed sockets are client-specific.

But you're misusing the `Pending` function. You should use the asynchronous methods `BeginAcceptSocket` or `AcceptAsync`. The `while(listener.Pending())` loop will exit as soon as no client is trying to connect, which will effectively prevent you from getting connections.

Comment: But what if several clients are trying to connect? would the loop work until I accept them all? I don't care about a "late" client.

Comment: No, it won't work unless all the clients connect at the exact same moment you open your server port. You may want to do something like this instead: `while(expectingOtherClients) { var sock = listener.AcceptSocket() /* your original code here */ }`

Comment: What I should put in instead expectingOtherClients? I don't know how many clients are trying to connect...

Comment: You said you don't care about "late" clients, so I supposed you have a means to distinguish a "late" client from an expected one... If you don't know how many clients are trying to connect, your best bet will still be to accept everyone, and then `expectingOtherClients` becomes `serverIsListening`. I'm afraid I can't tell you much more without knowing what behavior you're trying to implement. There are lots of `TcpListener` samples you can find, but every example will require you to know when you want to stop listening to incoming connections.

Comment: You don't need async IO at all to successfully accept clients. In fact almost all socket apps better not use async accept.